# Why is mousemove event firing 1px off the element?

Tags: javascript

I have an absolutely positioned element which has `left` property set to `250px`. I'm adding a  `mousemove` event listener to this element. So when the `mousemove` event fires, I'd expect `event.clientX` to be a minimum of 250. But the minimum I get is 249 which means the `mousemove` event is getting fired 1px off the element to which it is attached?

Example [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tsriram/pen/VwewmLb?editors=1111) - when you slowly move the mouse over the box from left, you can see the console log printing 249.

I'm using Chrome 83.0.4103.61 on Mac.

Screen recording:
[image]

Any idea why this could be?

Comment: I get 250 with Firefox on Windows (2x display scaling)

Comment: Can't reproduce, Chrome on MacOs shows `250`

Comment: I can only reproduce it if I set a negative left margin of 1px. (I only tested the positioning in the browser, haven't tested mouse event data in JS.)

Comment: Just added a screen recording to show what I'm seeing. And yeah I'm not seeing this in Firefox.

Comment: @Sriram I am getting the same as you. Did you ever find out why clientX is 1px off?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm getting a minimum of 250 and it seems from the other comments that other people aren't experiencing this as well.

However, if you you want to always ensure that it's at least 250, just use Math.max:

```
document.querySelector(".box").addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
  var x = Math.max(250, event.clientX);
  console.log("clientX", x);
});
```